# Inverse limits and sums

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ be a family of compact metric spaces such that $X_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $X_\beta$ for $\alpha<\beta$. Can we regard the disjoint sum $\bigsqcup_{\alpha<\omega_1} X_\alpha$ as a inverse limit of a certain inverse system consisting of $(X_\alpha)$?

Edit:
NO: Because an inverse limit of compact spaces is compact.

Comment: An inverse limit of compact **Hausdorff** spaces is compact; an inverse limit of compact non-Hausdorff spaces need not be.