# A non-compact inverse limit of compact spaces

Tags: general-topology

The inverse limit of a system of compact Hausdorff spaces is compact (and Hausdorff).  It is stated in a comment to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283020) that if the spaces are compact non-Hausdorff, the inverse limit need not be compact.

What would be an example of an inverse limit of compact spaces that is not compact?

Comment: See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18588/is-a-inverse-limit-of-compact-spaces-again-compact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Stealing" the mathoverflow answer, because it's so nice, and to have a self-contained site "here":

All spaces $X_n$ are on set $\{1,2,\dots\}$.  The space $X_n$ has the unique topology that makes $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ discrete and $\{n+1,n+2, \dots\}$ indiscrete. Of course $X_n$ is compact (the topology is finite) and non-Hausdorff.  Map $X_{n+1} \to X_n$ by the bijective map $f_{n+1}(x)=x$, which is continuous (as can easily be checked).  The inverse limit is $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ in the discrete topology (all "threads" are of the form $(n,n,n,\ldots)$ and have are isolated points in the limit as a subspace of $\prod_n X_n$, as can also easily be checked: we can take $\{n\}$ in the $n$-th component of a basic product open set etc.)

So the inverse limit of compact non-Hausdorff spaces can be very non-compact..